# Google internet authority is not shown as certificate issuer for Google.com

Tags: ssl, browser, proxy, ssl-certificate

When I am browsing websites via corporate proxy from my work location... The https websites visited shows issuer to be that of my company website and not of actual issuer.

For instance https://www.google.co.in certificate issuer shows CA as that of my company name. Normally the Google cert issuer is shown as Google Internet Authority.

Is it normal or Does that mean that everything I visit is readable with my company servers?

Comment: Ps: due to corporate restrictions, I cannot post a screenshot of same.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your company uses a transparent proxy that breaks SSL/TLS connections.

Technically this means that all traffic to/from the Internet can be monitored. 
What data your company is allowed to extract and store is however more a legal than a technical problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answers here.

Basically yes, my every traffic can be fully monitored even though my browsers do not show any warnings.

Warnings are not shown in my browser because it's been configured to use my company's CA as valid authority.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server

Comment: "it's been configured to use my company's CA as valid authority."  one has to remember/know that browsers are installed with hundreds of CAs, which are organizations that you "decide" to fully trust. If browsers were serious they should ask, one CA by one CA if you approve them, during install and any other change. Of course noone will understand the question and people will click "Yes to All"....